# How can I write url /:lang/display-cv-:cvid using zend_config?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-config

I got a zend_config file called routes.ini.

Currently my url looks like this /:LanguageCode/display-cv/:CVID

as defined by this route:

```
routes.display-cv.route = /:LanguageCode/display-cv/:CVID
routes.display-cv.defaults.controller = users-profile
routes.display-cv.defaults.action = display-cv
routes.display-cv.defaults.CVID =
routes.display-cv.reqs.CVID = "\d+"
routes.display-cv.defaults.LanguageCode = 'en'
routes.display-cv.reqs.LanguageCode = "[a-z]{2}"
```

which results in /en/display-cv/1

but my boss wants this instead:

```
/en/display-cv-1.html
```

I tried to simply change:

```
routes.display-cv.route = /:LanguageCode/display-cv/:CVID
```

to:
`routes.display-cv.route = /:LanguageCode/display-cv-:CVID.html` but the result is:
`/en/display-cv-:CVID.html`. it's considered a static url.

Then I call it this way:

```
<?php foreach ($this->CvList as $CV){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'action'        => 'display-cv',
    'CVID'          => $CV->CVID,
    'LanguageCode'  => 'en'
        ),'display-cv'); ?>">
   <?php echo $CV->CvName; ?> <BR/>
   </a>
<?php }  ?>
```

How can I change the configuration above to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex). For example, for your case I think that you could do:

```
resources.router.routes.display-cv.route = "(.+)/display-cv-(\d+)\.html"
resources.router.routes.display-cv.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex" 
resources.router.routes.display-cv.defaults.controller = users-profile
resources.router.routes.display-cv.defaults.action = display-cv
resources.router.routes.display-cv.map.1 = LanguageCode
resources.router.routes.display-cv.map.2 = id
resources.router.routes.display-cv.reverse = "/%s/display-cv-%d.html"
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
There was a mistake with ID and a revers url.

```
routes.display-cv.route = "(.+)/display-cv-(\d+)\.html"
routes.display-cv.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex" 
routes.display-cv.defaults.controller = users-profile
routes.display-cv.defaults.action = display-cv
routes.display-cv.map.1 = LanguageCode
routes.display-cv.map.2 = CVID
routes.display-cv.reverse = "%s/display-cv-%d.html"
```

Comment: very close. Now I have this:
href="//en/display-cv-1.html"
I'm not sure why my domain is gone.

Comment: @ndefontenay. Where do you have this href? When you use url view helper?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm in Mauritius. I've edited my question to show how I use the view helper.

Comment: @ndefontenay. I eddited the anwser.

Comment: Funny. I found it myself moments ago. I have another problem but it turns out there's a bug in my version of zend.

Thanks for your help though.